# Elastic Search query not working with an unreserved character

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to query a keyword that has a dot (.) appended to it. The query works fine on Kibana's console but not on my application's function. This is the function that creates the query given a keyword:

```
    searchOperation(keyWord:String){
    
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": ["message"],
            "query": keyWord + " AND \"DateID\""
          }
        }]
    }}}}
```

An example keyword that contains that character is: "BAD.IJH.KLM"

I append an escape character ('\') before and after the quotation marks so it becomes \"BAD.IJH.KLM\" and my query would look like this :

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "fields": ["message"],
            "query": "\"BAD.IJH.KLM\" AND \"DateID\""
          }
        }]
    }}}
```

but my query doesn't search for the exact keyword with the dots and instead searches for the first substring within "BAD.IJH.KLM" which is BAD in this example. How can I modify my keyword/query so the query searches for the exact string with characters that are not part of the reserved characters?

Comment: Can you please share the index mapping?

Comment: What analyzers have you used over the message field ?

Comment: @SahilGupta Due to privacy issues, I cannot share the index mapping. I am working on the front-end side so I am not quite sure what analyzers have been used by the back-end. I am only querying ELK on the front-end without any analyzers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you echo the value of your variable: keyWord it comes exactly as `"\"BAD.IJH.KLM\"`?

Comment: I do not need the quotation mark before the first escape character. When I echo the value comes exactly as \"BAD.IJH.KLM\"